# How to add new column and fill it with random values?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

How to add a column to an existing table and insert random positive integers?

```
SELECT id, views, name
FROM buysell_product
WHERE views >= 30
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Data:

| id | views | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 72 | Excellent Hyundai creta sx doctor used with financ |
| 2 | 41 | Excellent 2013 ford ecosport taitanium pushstar (Ford) |
| 5 | 39 | iPhone 11 128gb with vat & insurance |
| 9 | 37 | Volkswagen Polo 1.2 GT AMT 2017 |
| 57 | 35 | Iphone 13 and 14 |
| 44 | 34 | Usupso Massage Anti Skid Slippers-Size 40/41 |

I want to add column `random_views`.

Answer (score 2):

**Original SQLite DB with table `buysell_product`**

```
SELECT id, views, name
FROM buysell_product
WHERE views >= 30
ORDER BY views DESC
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  views   name
3   72  Excellent Hyundai creta 
2   41  Excellent 2013 ford 
5   39  iPhone 11 128gb 
9   37  Volkswagen Polo 1.2 GT AMT 2017
57  35  Iphone 13 and 14
44  34  Usupso Massage Anti Skid Slippers
```

**To add a new column** use the `ALTER` method on the table
with `ADD COLUMN` to add a new column named `random_views`

```
ALTER TABLE buysell_product 
ADD COLUMN random_views;
```

now use `UPDATE` to update the table
and `SET` to set the values for the new column,
the values I added are positive integers between 1 and 100

```
UPDATE buysell_product 
SET random_views = abs(random()) % (100) + 1
```

now view the updated table

```
SELECT id, views, random_views, name
FROM buysell_product
WHERE random_views >= 50
ORDER BY random_views DESC
```

OUTPUT

```
id  page_views  random_views    name
54  7   98  Fully Furnished Office Space Available
8   19  97  Nissan magnite
47  28  92  Ortega Guitars Ukulele, Right - Rufire
9   37  91  Volkswagen Polo 1.2 GT AMT 2017
53  12  91  Scorpio
51  19  86  Thrift Earrings
44  34  79  Usupso Massage Anti Skid Slippers
7   12  77  Excellent Hyundai creta 
56  6   75  Samsung S22
46  13  70  Meditating Smoke Ganesha Fountain
60  24  70  Headphone
58  11  68  Vector X exercise ball
5   39  67  iPhone 11 128gb 
67  15  67  Universal Touch Screen Capacitive Stylus
```

Comment: *`ALTER TABLE buysell_product ADD COLUMN random_views;`* - this statement is incorrect, it will cause Error 1064. You must add complete column definition.

Comment: *`UPDATE buysell_product SET random_views = abs(random()) % (100) + 1`* - this statement is incorrect. (#1) There is no `RANDOM()` function in MySQL; (#2) If you'd fix and use `RAND()` then it generates non-negative float value in [0,1), so ABS() usage makes no sense. (#3) Your `random_views` column in shown output seems to be INTEGER, so this expression cannot produce the value other than 1 or 2, i.e. the output does not match the code.

Comment: @Akina
It's SQLite DB. And, the posted answers are verified by me running on my SQLite DB with the same queries I posted in the answer.

Comment: *It's SQLite DB.* I see that the question is tagged as MySQL-relative. You provide a solution - it must match all tags.